# calculating coordinates of a triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have the following situation:
I have three constant points: $P_1(a_1, b_1, 0), P_2(a_2, b_2, 0), P_3(a_3, b_3, 0)$. These points are on a cartesian 3d space and form an equilateral triangle with a side length equal to `len1`.

I also have a second equilateral triangle let's call it $T$ (in the same 3d space) with a side length equal to `len2 < len1` defined by three points $T_1(x_1, y_1, z_1), T_2(x_2, y_2, z_2), T_3(x_3, y_3, z_3)$ and a constraint: $z_1, z_2, z_3 > 0$.

my first question is:

For all possible values of $(x_1, y_1, z_1), (x_2, y_2, z_2), (x_3, y_3, z_3)$, i.e. for all possible positions of triangle $T$ with side length =`len2` and $z>0$, is there a unique vector $(L_1, L_2, L_3)$ where $L_1 = Dist(P_1, T_1), L_2 = Dist(P_2, T_2), L_3 = Dist(P_3, T_3)$?

my second question is:
If the answer to the previous question is yes, then given $L_1, L_2, L_3$ what are the equations for finding the coordinates of the three points $T_1, T_2, T_3$ of triangle $T$?

Thank you in advance.

**Edit: the winding order of the triangle is the same, i.e. always $T_1,T_2,T_3$, not possible to have $T_3, T_1, T_2$ or other combinations. The minimum angle of the face normal of triangle $T$ with $z=0$ is $>0$ degrees. Just mentioning this to avoid situations like placing the triangle face down.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine to have a wood board representing $xy$ plane, with three pins at `P1, P2, P3`. Attach to each pin a string of length `L1, L2, L3` and to the loose end of the strings attach a vertex of triangle `T`. It is obvious that you have infinitely many positions of that triangle with all strings tight, hence the answer to your first question is NO.

Comment: yes, I'm not sure I can visualize having all three strings tight and the triangle at different positions, trying it in my head now

Comment: ok yes i can visualize it now. Thank you. What would help? If the plane of the triangle `T` was known?

Comment: Yes, it's possible that knowing the plane of `T` could help. I'm not sure, though.